# email template sent instead of actual email

Tags: email, templates

This is a weird one.  I wanted to send an email to four specific Contacts, all members of one of our Groups.  I searched to display the Group list, selected the four contacts, and gave the action to "Send email (50 or less)".  I used an older template to get started, but edited it extensively, added myself as a bcc, and sent it out.  Seemed to go just great.

I later discovered that one of the four did not receive the email, but instead received (at the exact same time as the other emails) the text of the template I used to draft the email.  When I look in his Activities, it shows the email as having been sent as part of the batch with four others, and when I view that entry it shows me the email as edited.  But I am quite confident he received the template version.  And incidentally, I did NOT receive a bcc of whatever was sent to him.

I'm using WordPress and CiviCRM, current versions.  Has anyone else experienced anything like this?  Is it a bug, or might I have done something wrong somehow?  How can I prevent it happening again?

Thanks!